# str_replace() not working as expected

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I'm trying to replace the `src` attribute of images in a string `$content` using `str_replace`.

The `src` of these images usually links to `../img/article/foo.jpg` but I want each iteration to be set to `img/article/foo.jpg` instead.

My code is like this:

```
$content = str_replace('../img/article', 'img/article', $content);
```

This doesn't return any changes to the `$content`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is the full function to sanitize the user's input:

```
function remove_styles($text) {
    $content = trim($content);
    $content = preg_replace('#(<[a-z ]*)(style=("|\')(.*?)("|\'))([a-z ]*>)#', '\\1\\6', $text);
    $content = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $content);
    $content = strip_tags($content,'<h2><h3><p><strong><a><ul><li><img>');
    $content = str_replace('../img/article','img/article',$content);
    return $content;
}
```

This removes styles, trims whitespace, strips tags and corrects the relative path.

The content is from the TinyMCE editor, and a sample looks like this:

```
<p data-wr_replaced="true">Your job search has gone well. You've aced the interviews, you've worked through the technical tests, you've wowed the partners and you've finally got the offer you were looking for at the firm you've always wanted to work at.</p>
<p data-wr_replaced="true">But when you want to resign, your current workplace offers you more. More money, more holiday, more opportunity.</p>
<p data-wr_replaced="true">Now I'm not going to say what you should or shouldn't do - there are plenty of other guides giving you very clear advice out there:</p>
<p> <img src="../img/article/6a3184a558a98656e900f4aa106c387c.png" alt="" width="479" height="662" /></p>
```

The image is uploaded via the WYSIWYG editor and saves the relative path, which is incorrect on the page where the article ends up being displayed.

Comment: What is `$content` before you try to `str_replace` it?

Comment: The code looks fine. Need a dump of $content to see what is going on :)

Comment: `$content` is an article written by users of the site using a WYSIWYG editor, and can contain `h2`, `h3`, `p`, `strong`, `a`, `ul`, `li` and `img` tags.

Comment: It works for me. http://www.tehplayground.com/#UOnMOUj4c So maybe the $content before is wrong.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan post some $content data for checking.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan Still, show us an example of where the `str_replace` doesn't work. Provide the `$content`, show the code that should replace `$content`, and show us `$content` after the replace.

Comment: If `$content` is an article written by a user, it will hardly contain a relative path to an image, would it?

Comment: Please see my edit for more information. @martinstoeckli, yes it would.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan - Even with your function, the replacement works fine: http://www.tehplayground.com/#HGNXudPCl . Note that in function `remove_styles()` your first line reads the global(?) variable `$content` instead of the parameter `$text`, this leads to a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code looks fine. If you still can't get it working, try preg_replace.

This will match *any* link that is '../' and strip it out. If you only want to do img/etc then change the part in brackets.

```
$content = '../img/article/ttt.jpg';
$content = preg_replace('/\.\.\/(.+)/', '$1', $content);
echo $content;
```

And if you want to get rid of multiple levels of '../' then:

```
$content = '../../img/article/ttt.jpg';
$content = preg_replace('/(\.\.\/)+(.+)/', '$2', $content);
echo $content;
```

[Demo of the above code here.](http://www.tehplayground.com/#gcx2d1NDp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture grouping with `preg_replace` function  :

```
$content = preg_replace('/[\w/]+/(\w+/\w+)/i', '$1', $content);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU6tH1/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do?
Find the links in the $content (posted by users) and replace the url in images from "../" to just "/"

```
$content = "<h1>This is the article header</h1> <p>This is a paragraph</p> <img src='..img/article/foo.jpg' alt='this is a image which src i want to replace'/>";

$find = "..img/article";
$replace = "img/article";
$content = str_replace($find,$replace,$content);

echo $content;
```

http://www.tehplayground.com/#ujK2N2ldQ

Comment: Your code is the same as OP's in the question, what's your point?

Comment: i have $content declared before i try to str_replace it, nothing in OP's code declares $content before he tries to apply str_replace

Comment: Well, obviously it was declared somewhere before, as OP wrote in comment: "`$content` is an article written by users ... ". Your code doesn't make much sense, why not use directly `$content = "img/article/image/image.png";` on the first line?

Comment: Where does he say it is declared? The thing is, if it was, there is no reason it would not work.. based on the information OP has given us i can only assume `$content` is not declared before he tries to apply `str_replace`.